# I seem to be getting strace info on every bash command. How do I stop it?

Tags: strace

This is what I get when I type ls in a terminal:
(It doesn't happen when I login as root. Only when I am the js user.

```
js@hp-suse-laptop:~$ ls
      7255:
      7255:     file=libselinux.so.1 [0];  needed by ls [0]
      7255:     file=libselinux.so.1 [0];  generating link map
      7255:       dynamic: 0x00007f860df90d30  base: 0x00007f860df69000   size: 0x000000000002aa88
      7255:         entry: 0x00007f860df70ba0  phdr: 0x00007f860df69040  phnum:                 10
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     file=libcap.so.2 [0];  needed by ls [0]
      7255:     file=libcap.so.2 [0];  generating link map
      7255:       dynamic: 0x00007f860df67df8  base: 0x00007f860df61000   size: 0x0000000000007308
      7255:         entry: 0x00007f860df63330  phdr: 0x00007f860df61040  phnum:                  9
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by ls [0]
      7255:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      7255:       dynamic: 0x00007f860df599e0  base: 0x00007f860dd9b000   size: 0x00000000001c5338
      7255:         entry: 0x00007f860ddc1e30  phdr: 0x00007f860dd9b040  phnum:                 12
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     file=libpcre.so.1 [0];  needed by /lib64/libselinux.so.1 [0]
      7255:     file=libpcre.so.1 [0];  generating link map
      7255:       dynamic: 0x00007f860dd99de0  base: 0x00007f860dd03000   size: 0x0000000000097208
      7255:         entry: 0x00007f860dd051f0  phdr: 0x00007f860dd03040  phnum:                  9
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by /lib64/libselinux.so.1 [0]
      7255:     file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
      7255:       dynamic: 0x00007f860dd01cf0  base: 0x00007f860dcfe000   size: 0x0000000000004090
      7255:         entry: 0x00007f860dcff130  phdr: 0x00007f860dcfe040  phnum:                  9
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     calling init: /lib64/libc.so.6
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     calling init: /lib64/libdl.so.2
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     calling init: /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     calling init: /usr/lib64/libcap.so.2
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     calling init: /lib64/libselinux.so.1
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     initialize program: ls
      7255:
      7255:
      7255:     transferring control: ls
      7255:
bin/  Desktop/  Development/  Development.zip  Documents/  Downloads/  Music/  Pictures/  Public/  snap/  Templates/  Videos/
js@hp-suse-laptop:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not strace info and looks nothing like strace info. It's debugging output from the dynamic linker. You're getting it because the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable is set (probably to `files`). See [`man 8 ld.so`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for more about it. You can stop it in a given shell with `unset LD_DEBUG`. If new shells have it, then you need to look for it in `.bash_profile` and similar files.